# TCA Checkbox: Set default value by itemsProcFunc

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I want to set the default value of a checkbox (TCA type "check") with a condition to some other values (if type = 100 -> checked, else not checked).

Therefor I created an ItemsProcFunc, which is executed. The value is set, if I debug my output, but has no influence on the form.

```
'property_name' => [
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'check',
            'items' => [
                '1' => [
                    '0' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_core.xlf:labels.enabled'
                ]
            ],
            'itemsProcFunc' => 'Vendor\\Extension\\Backend\\Event\\ItemsProcFunc->getCheckboxDefaultValue',
        ]
    ],
```

The method, where I set the default value:

```
public static function getCheckboxDefaultValue(&$config)
{
    $config['config']['default'] = 1;
}
```

If I debug $config, the value is set correctly, but gets lost on its way to the form.

```
array(6 items)
    items => array(1 item)
    config => array(4 items)
    type => 'check' (5 chars)
    items => array(1 item)
    default => 1 (integer)
    itemsProcFunc => 'Vendor\Extension\Backend\Event\ItemsProcFunc->getCheckboxDefaultValue'
```

Any hints appreciated.

Comment: `itemsProcFunc` is meant to change/add/remove items. You can't change any other field configuration like `default` with it. I don't think there is an easy way to set conditional defaults.

Comment: Ah, OK. Sounds logic. ITEMSprodfunc :-)
Thanks for your quick reply.